# creating a favorites function for mobile app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver, favorites

I have just started creating a recipe mobile app and I want to have it so that people can hit the favorites button and their recipe will show up in the favorites list. I would like to know how to set this up so if anyone knows any tutorials it would be a great help. 
I am using jquery mobile and Dreamweaver.

Comment: Elaborate a little... maybe post some code you found/tried.

Answer (score 1):

Simple dude just make one `database` according to `user ID` and `place that all favorites` in that database whenever any user come in that list just  fetch the value of favorites according to user ID i.e all `value will be unique for every user`

Comment: Thanks that the sort of thing I'm after. I'm still learning this stuff so do you know any guides that will show me how to do this. thanks